# only execute script when url does not contain anchor sign

Tags: jquery, url, hash, comments, show-hide

I have the following script working on my site at www.riscograma.ro, to hide the comments section unless told otherwise:

```
jQuery(function($)  {
$('#comments').hide();
$('#showcomments').click(function(e)    {
    if($('#comments').is(':hidden'))    {
        $('#comments').show();
}   }); });
```

The problem is that links to individual comments or to the reply form can no longer point where they should, because the target is hidden.

I figured the way around this would be to only execute the script if there is no anchor sign (#) in the url. I tried adding the following line (and variations):

```
jQuery(function($)  {
if(window.location.hash.indexOf("#")==0)    {
    $('#comments').hide();  }
    $('#showcomments').click(function(e)    {
        if($('#comments').is(':hidden'))    {
            $('#comments').show();
}   }); });
```

But it doesn't work (i.e. the comments div becomes visible at all times).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf` will return `-1` if not found, `0` would indicate it was found at index `0`.

Comment: that's what he's trying to do: if it's found then he hides the comment

Comment: @Gavriel '_only execute the script if there is no anchor sign (#) in the url'_ is not what the code does; this executes the code if the anchor exists, and only if the anchor is at index 0.

Comment: window.location.hash will either be empty string or a string that starts with "#" (which will be then found on index 0) so it does in a way check it's existance, but you're right, that it's the opposite way, so he should check == -1 or != 0

Comment: Thanks alot Mr. D, that did it! So, for anyone who needs this, the correct code is:
`code`    jQuery(function($)  {
if(window.location.hash.indexOf("#")==-1)    {
    $('#comments').hide();  }
    $('#showcomments').click(function(e)    {
        if($('#comments').is(':hidden'))    {
            $('#comments').show();
}   }); }); `code`